# In how many ways can $6$ girls and $8$ boys be arranged in a row if no two girls should stand next to each other?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A teacher has 6 girls and 8 boys to arrange in for a choir. Determine the number of ways she can arrange the 14 children in a single row if no two girls should stand next to each other.

How do you  do this?  I just need to know how to solve this. You can use another example to explain this to me because this question is very tricky to me .

Comment: Try 2 girls and 1 boy. Then 2 girls and 2 boys etc. to determine what the constraints are, and how many arrangements are possible satisfying the constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Strategy:

1. Arrange the eight boys in a row.
2. This creates nine spaces, seven between successive boys and two at the ends of the row in which we can place the girls.
   $$\square b \square b \square b \square b \square b \square b \square b \square b \square$$
   To separate the girls, choose six of these spaces in which to place the six girls.
3. Arrange the six girls in the chosen spaces.

Comment: Am i correct to say that:                                   Place all 8 boys in a row. 
There are 8! ways to do this. 

There are now 9 positions into which the 6 girls can go: 
| B | B | B | B | B | B | B | B | 

There are P(9,6) ways of placing the 6 girls into these 9 positions. 

8! * 9!/3! = 2,438,553,600

Comment: @Mapoz  That is correct.